# Can't connect from one docker container to another by its public domain name

Tags: docker, networking

I have an application composed of containerized web-services deployed with docker-compose (it's a test env). One of the containers is nginx that operates as a reverse proxy for services and also serves static files. A public domain name points to the host machine and nginx has a server section that utilizes it.

The problem I am facing is that I can't talk to nginx by that public domain name from the containers launched on this same machine - connection always timeouts. (For example, I tried doing a `curl https://<mypublicdomain>.com`)

Referring by the containers name (using docker's hostnames) works just fine. Reuqests to the same domain name from other machines also work ok.

I understand this has to do with how docker does networking, but fail to find any docs that would outline what exactly goes wrong here. Could anyone explain the root of the issue to me or maybe just point in the right direction?

(For extra context: originally I was going to use this to set up monitoring with prometheus and blackbox exporter to make it see the server the same way anyone from the outside would do + to automatically check that SSL is working. For now I pulled back to point the prober to nginx by its docker hostname)

**Nginx image**

```
FROM nginx:stable
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

COPY ./dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem /dhparam-2048.pem

COPY ./index.html /var/www/index.html

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
networks:
  mainnet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  my-gateway:
    container_name: my-gateway
    image: aturok/manuwor_gateway:latest
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - mainnet
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    expose:
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - /var/stuff:/var/www
      - /var/certs:/certsdir
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

(I show only the nginx service, as others are irrelevant - I would for example spin up a nettools container and not connect it to the `mainnet` network - still expect the requests to reach nginx, since I am using the public domain name. The problem also happens with the containers connected to the same network)

**nginx.conf** (normally it comes with a bunch of env vars, replaced + removed irrelevant backend)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /certsdir/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /certsdir/privkey.pem;

        
        server_tokens off;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /dhparam-2048.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;



        root /var/www/;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            root /var/www;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: certificates are ok when I access the server from elsewhere*

Comment: nginx config? docker-compose file?

Comment: Are mapping ports from the host to the nginx container?

Comment: added configs; yes, ports are mapped